# ActiveRecord::Base.connection.query_cache_enabled in sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, activerecord

I have a piece of code that performs the same queries over and over, and it's doing that in a background worker within a thread.

I checkout out the activerecord query cache middleware but apparently it needs to be enabled before use. However I'm not sure if it's a safe thing to do and if it will affect other running threads.

you can see the tests here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3e36db4406beea32772b1db1e9a16cc1e8aea14c/activerecord/test/cases/query_cache_test.rb#L19

my question is: can I borrow and/or use the middleware directly to enable query cache for the duration of a block safely in a thread?

when I tried `ActiveRecord::Base.cache do` my CI started failing left and right...

Comment: newest sidekiq versions (5 I think) should do this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT:** **Rails 5 and later:** the ActiveRecord query cache is automatically enabled even for background jobs like Sidekiq (see: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#activerecord-query-cache for information on how to disable it).

**Rails 4.x and earlier:**
The difficulty with applying ActiveRecord::QueryCache to your Sidekiq workers is that, aside from the implementation details of it being a middleware, it's meant to be built during the request and destroyed at the end of it. Since background jobs don't have a request, you need to be careful about when you clear the cache. A reasonable approach would be to cache only during the `perform` method, though.

So, to implement that, you'll probably need to write your own piece of Sidekiq middleware, based on [ActiveRecord::QueryCache](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2a7cf24cb7aab28f483a6772b608e2868a9030ba/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb#L30) but following [Sidekiq's middleware guide](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Middleware). E.g.,

```
class SidekiqQueryCacheMiddleware
  def call(worker, job, queue)
    connection    = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    enabled       = connection.query_cache_enabled
    connection_id = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_id
    connection.enable_query_cache!

    yield
  ensure
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_id = connection_id
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.clear_query_cache
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disable_query_cache! unless enabled
  end
end
```

Comment: Robert, [ActiveRecord::QueryCache has evolved since](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb), and it looks like it is caching all the connection pool now. Do you think it would still be a good idea to cache a single connection, or should we cache all of them?

Comment: @UlysseBN actually, since Rails 5, the query cache is automatically enabled even for background jobs like Sidekiq (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#activerecord-query-cache). So my answer is really only for Rails < 5; for Rails >= 5, the cache is already enabled. Thanks for the note; I'll update my answer!